# TypeScript Partial of Union complains about assigning a unioned value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create TypeScript interfaces for a query object.

```ts
interface Comparison {
    op: '=' | '>' | '<';
    field: string;
    value: any;
}

interface Conjunction {
    op: 'and' | 'or';
    queries: Array<Comparison>;
}

type Query = Comparison | Conjunction;
```

So the query can either be simple (Comparison) like

```json
{
    "op": "=",
    "field": "score",
    "value": 5
}
```

or more complex (Conjunction) like

```json
{
    "op": "and",
    "queries": [
        {
            "op": ">",
            "field": "score",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "op": "<",
            "field": "score",
            "value": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm ultimately mapping some input filter object into my query object.

```ts
// One possible input for a simple comparison filter
// const inputFilter = {
//     field: 'someField',
//     type: 'eq',
//     value: 'someValue'
// };

// An input for a more complex filter
const inputFilter = {
    field: 'someField',
    type: 'range',
    value: 5,
    valueEnd: 10
};

const query: Partial<Query> = {
    field: inputFilter.field
};

switch (inputFilter.type) {
    case 'eq':
        query.op = '=';
        query.value = inputFilter.value;
        break;
    case 'range':
        query.op = 'and'; // ERROR: Type '"and"' is not assignable to type '"=" | ">" | "<" | undefined'
        query.queries = [
            { field: inputFilter.field, op: '>', value: inputFilter.value },
            { field: inputFilter.field, op: '<', value: inputFilter.valueEnd }
        ]; // ERROR: Property 'queries' does not exist on type 'Partial<Comparison>'
        break;
    // ...other cases / default...
}
```

I get two errors. The first is when I try to set `query.op` to `'and'`

> `Type '"and"' is not assignable to type '"=" | ">" | "<" | undefined'`

The second is when I type to set `query.queries`

> `Property 'queries' does not exist on type 'Partial<Comparison>'`

Here is a [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOVgDO6IyA3gFDJXLrYBcyA5ALyPIA+TAfG54wDyMA3JWoxgEADYATBgTD4QAcxHVkANziSArhAZwQATxEBfcuVCRYiFBhAArbSARhgxMqKq0GjA9N5M6FDCnsgAjrr4EAQMGDh4hMQA2gC6puZghtgoAIqRhsjMaFi4+EQknHaOzq7EIuQA9A3IALRt5k3IAPIgKNjoBATAAEaSKKDY2mCNzQjE8sgTUwBiwJJWhR6dauJSskxEmBCre4wANDNqyJnZPhBh55dqmjp6B1gQAGpauoyXJvVOgBBEDoMAAC2gyH6gxGY0WIEm0zmIAWSzAq3WUKKFB2EhkPkOx3x-guahub0YUAMSggj2ePzeAFYydQXroAKIgfYARgADOQAeYUQsItBDAwAAp4Vxafh5cVcTa4sQkhjozFWAB0uxkgvqBAA7sAwAhwcgABQatbaikASg8agQcAIKEY90YdFCajFUEMWtomxYISu1F9-vZKCK1qxUC1kdUoeQwygEDgAGtE1Rna6mNTlHSvUnwvkA9gg34Q0nw1rfRICJskt6k6RkLr9jHte2zjR6NxzhpGerESsbdB44zkCZWcWqK328OkZrx93ez5BD3I4vR7GJ68udIp82qGlj8nUxms8hOlrb2DIVBkDnotfkNIIPBtOtb1rBUA) to see it in action.

Am I misunderstanding what `Partial<Query>` is doing? I was hoping it meant that I can have a partial comparison or partial conjunction object.

For the record, using `Partial<Comparison> | Partial<Conjunction>` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Conjunction` objects don't have a `field` attribute

```
interface Conjunction {
    op: 'and' | 'or';
    queries: Comparison[];
}

const query: Partial<Query> = {
    field: inputFilter.field
};
```

which means your query will always be of type `Comparison`.